# AJAX call during authenticated service

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, authorization

```
function getschoolDetail() {

    var installationId = $('#school_installationId').val();
    var header = make_base_auth ('rmspeint', '12345678');
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://xyx.com/nnn/ex?param=' + abc,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",

        beforeSend: function(req) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 
                       make_base_auth ('user', 'pass'));
        },
        success: function(data) {
        alert("pass")
        },
        error: function() {
            alert(fail);
        }
    });
}


function make_base_auth(user, password) {

      var tok = user + ':' + password;
      var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
      return "Basic " + hash;
}
```

I am making an AJAX call in above manner, but every time it fails.

However, when I am doing the same call through the browser, it is successful.

I get the following error:

> "Authorization Basic cm1zcGVpbnQ6MTIzNDU2Nzg=" is missing from request header

make_base_auth returns right value I matched the value.

Comment: Have you confirmed in a debugger that the Authorization header in the AJAX request is the same as when you send the request through your browser?

Comment: You have a typo, a single-quote out of place that I removed.

Comment: You can check your headers with firebug or another tool that show's the ajax request.

Comment: I solved the problem every thing is right. Cross domain call is the problem